# what am i wrong with my arrays?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make a menu list based on roles, but when I want to display them to my home view it doesnt show up the list.. how can I fix it? the problem is that the menu list is not showing with separates files.
controller

```
public function getModules($id_module){
        if($this->session->userdata('log')){
            $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
            $menu = array();
            $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
            foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion){
               $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
                $seccions[$index]['data']= $modules;
                if (!count($seccions[$index]['data']))
                    unset($seccions[$index]);
            }
            foreach ($seccions as $item)
                array_push($menu,$item);
          $this->data['fields'] = $menu;
          $this->load->view('modules_view',$this->data);
        }
    }
```

model

```
public function get_rows(){
        $this->db->select('id,seccion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_seccion');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

    public function query($query){
        return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    }
```

view

home.php

```
 <section class="content">
          <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
          <div class="row">
            <h3 class="text-center">Welcome to storeLTE, click a module below to get started!</h3>
              <div class="home_module_list">
                  <div class="module_item">
                       <?php $this->load->view('modules_view'); ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Main row -->
          <div class="row">
            <!-- Left col -->
            <section class="col-lg-12 connectedSortable">
            </section>
          </div>
        </section>
```

modules

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<div class="module_item">
    <?php foreach ($fields as $session) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($session['data'] as $itemData) : ?>
            <div class="module_item" title="<?= $itemData['value'] ?>">
                <a href="<?= $itemData['url'] ?>"><img src="<?= $itemData['icon'] ?>"/></a>
                <a href="<?= $itemData['url'] ?>"><?= $itemData['value']?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Try printing what you get in your `menu` variable

Comment: Nothing gets displayed or does it display empty divs? Has your environment been setup to work with shorthand PHP?

Answer (score 0):

try this at your model

```
public function get_rows(){
    $this->db->select('id,seccion');
    $this->db->from('storelte_seccion');
    $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }
```

Comment: so basically you dont have an array so that is why you cant use result_array();

Comment: the array is on getModules